# jquery getScript(url) duplicates calls

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this piece of jquery code implemented for infinite scroll on page:

```
paginate = function() {
  if ($('.pagination').length) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var url;
      url = $('.pagination a.next_page').attr('href');
      if (url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50) {
        $('.loader').removeClass('hidden');
        return $.getScript(url);
      }
    });
    return $(window).scroll();
  }
};

$(document).on("page:load ready", paginate);
```

problem is that when this function is called I see in developer_tools/network 2 get requests to the same url, this happens randomly, might be 1 request, might be 2.

[image]

Can't find the solution for a few days now. In a desperate need of help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, before the script is done loading, the scroll event can theoretically be fired lots of times. One way to work around this would be this:

```
paginate = function() {
  if ($('.pagination').length) {
    $(window).scroll(scrollHandler);
    return $(window).scroll();
  }
};

scrollHandler = function() {
  var url;
  url = $('.pagination a.next_page').attr('href');
  if (url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50) {
    $('.loader').removeClass('hidden');
    $(window).unbind('scroll');
    return $.getScript(url, function() {
      $(window).bind(scrollHandler);
    });
  }
};
```

The idea behind this is to unbind the scroll event when the script is requested, and once the script is loaded, rebind it.

Comment: Almost there, it sends ONE get request when I scroll down to the bottom, but it does not send any more requests when I keep scrolling down. It calls the paginate function only once, while I am 100% sure there are more pages to load. The updated javascript based on your answer looks like this: https://gist.github.com/rmagnum2002/469c7267ccdc626b6ac4

Comment: Found an working example, thank you very much for your time. +1

Comment: No problem at all. :)

Answer (score 0):

Found an working example, sends 1 get request each time.

**Coffee script:**

```
onEndless = ->
  url = undefined
  $(window).off "scroll", onEndless
  url = $(".pagination a.next_page").attr("href")

  if url and $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 150
    $(".loader").removeClass "hidden"
    $.getScript url, ->
      $(window).on "scroll", onEndless

  else
    $(window).on "scroll", onEndless

$(window).on "scroll", onEndless
$(window).scroll()
```

**JS:**

```
var onEndless;

onEndless = function() {
  var url;
  $(window).off('scroll', onEndless);
  url = $('.pagination a.next_page').attr('href');
  // $('.pagination').hide();
  if (url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 150) {
    $('.loader').removeClass('hidden');
    return $.getScript(url, function() {
      return $(window).on('scroll', onEndless);
    });
  } else {
    return $(window).on('scroll', onEndless);
  }
};

$(window).on('scroll', onEndless);

$(window).scroll();
```

Comment: Just bear in mind that you now unbind and rebind the event on *every* scroll which is very expensive performance-wise and might slow down your site.

Comment: Well @MartinDenk, I am still opened to better ideas. :) So if you have some improvements on this code, don't hesitate to write them in your answer and I'll accept it with pleasure. I am noob in js that's why bind/unbind for me didn't looked expensive.